# How do I create a slideshow images with more pageviews on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, slideshow, pageviews

I want to make users click one forward/backward button and increase one pageview. For example, 20 slide images will have 20 pageviews. 
Now I have follow W3 sample to make this slideshow (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp). However, this will not crease a pageviews.

Answer (score 0):

To send a page view (assuming Google Analytics is loaded):

`ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);`

More on that here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Could add the `ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);` code within the onClick handler for the forward/backward buttons, or within the slider code transitions to the next/previous slide.